# WooCommerce override function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to override a function in woocommerce, specifically -
woocommerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php (the wc_cart_totals_order_total_html function).

I could edit the function directly (it outputs html that needs to be changed), but I'd prefer not to as I'll lose changes on updates.

I'm sure it's a common thing, I'm just not quite sure how to go about doing that. If I copy the function to functions.php in my theme, I get an error about re-declaring the function.

Comment: Override the template to what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old topic, but maybe I could help a bit. I had similar problem. I wanted to override currencies, and add a custom currency. The functions are in woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php

```
function get_woocommerce_currencies() {
return array_unique(
    apply_filters( 'woocommerce_currencies',
        array(
```

The other function is:

```
function get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency = '' ) {
if ( ! $currency ) {
    $currency = get_woocommerce_currency();
}

switch ( $currency ) {
    ...
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_currency_symbol', $currency_symbol, $currency );
```

This is the code I've put in functions.php of my child theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_my_currency' );

function add_my_currency( $currencies ) {
$currencies['RSD'] = __( 'Serbian dinar', 'woocommerce' );
return $currencies;
}
```